# Automatic sliding window shutter

Tags: motor, design, microcontroller, automation

I want to build an automatic sliding window shutter and need help
with part selection and dimensioning.

Some assumptions:

- window width 1.4 m
- sliding shutter weight 25 kg
- max speed 0.07 m/s
- max acceleration 0.035 m/s^2
- pulley diameter 0.04m.

Leaving out friction I need a motor with about 0.02 Nm of torque and a rated speed of 33 rpm.

What I would like to use:

- [motor controller](http://electromen.com/en/products/item/motor-controllers/dc-motor-below-10A/EM-140A) with soft-start and jam protection,
- [dc motor 24V](https://www.maedler.de/product/1643/1331/1979/1349/stirnrad-kleingetriebemotoren-sf-24-v-bis-2-nm),
- [Pulleys and timing belts](https://www.maedler.de/product/1643/1616/986/zahnriemenraeder-t25-fuer-riemenbreite-10-mm-aus-aluminium).

Would you suggest other components or a different setup?
How do I connect motor and pulleys (clamping set?)?
Do I need additional [bearings](https://www.maedler.de/product/1643/1629/stehlager) because of the radial load?

```
M=P
M=B=P
M=P=B
M=B=P=B
```

(M motor, P pulley, B bearing, = shaft)

If so I have to extend the motor shaft. What would I use for that (clamp collars, couplings?)?
What width do I need for the belts? Which belt profile (T, AT, HDT) should I use?

**Update**

The construction I am aiming for resembles the one which can be seen on page 6 (pdf numbering) [here](http://www.baier-gmbh.de/media/docs/schiebeladen/Schiebeladen-e.pdf).

Comment: Hi tauran.  At the moment, this question seems a bit too broad -- you're asking about a varied mix of big and small system components.  It's also unclear what the mechanical constraints are; would a garage door opening system work?  Would the motor from an automotive power window system work?  Why or why not?

Comment: This is a question for [engineering.se] or [diy.se]. Not everything that has a motor is a robot.

Answer (score 1):

"Leaving out friction I need a motor with about 0.02 Nm [of torque] and [a rated speed of] 33 rpm."

No offense, but verifying your numbers based on your spec's:

> window width 1.4 m
>
> sliding shutter weight 25 kg
>
> max speed 0.07 m/s
>
> max acceleration 0.035 m/s^2
>
> pulley diameter 0.04m.

The max linear speed is equal to $r\omega$, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity in radians per second. Your pulley diameter is 0.04m, so your radius is 0.02m. This means that:

$$
v = r\omega \\
0.07 \mbox{m/s} = 0.02\mbox{m}*\omega \\
\omega = \frac{0.07}{0.02} \mbox{rad/s} \\
\omega = \frac{3.5 \mbox{rad/s}}{1}*\frac{60\mbox{s}}{1\mbox{m}}*\frac{1\mbox{rev}}{2\pi\mbox{rad}} \\
\omega = 33.4\mbox{rpm}
$$

So, your rated speed checks out. Now, the torque. If you ignore friction, then the only purpose for torque is to accelerate:

$$
\tau = I\alpha \\
$$

where $I$ is the moment of inertia, $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration is $\mbox{rad}/s^2$, and $\tau$ is the motor torque. Again, $a=r\alpha$, like $v = r\omega$, so $\alpha = a/r$. As the weight of the shutter is going to the pulley, you can consider it a point mass at radius $r$, meaning the moment of inertia $I = mr^2$.

So:

$$
\tau = I\alpha \\
\tau = (mr^2)(a/r) \\
\tau = r(ma) \\
\tau = (0.02\mbox{m})(25*0.035\mbox{kg m/s}^2) \\
\tau = 0.0175 \mbox{Nm} \\
$$

BUT - if this is for a *vertical* shutter, the motor has to support the weight of the shutter while it's accelerating it, so the moment of inertia is now $mgr$, or $25*9.81*0.02 = 4.9\mbox{Nm}$ - this dwarfs your acceleration requirement.

The required torque is small enough that I would suggest double checking your assumption that friction is negligible. That said, you have a rated speed and a rated torque, now you just need a rated power. For rotating systems:

$$
P = \tau\omega \\
$$

Where the previously calculated values torque and speed are $\omega = 3.5 \mbox{rad/s}$ and $\tau = 0.0175 \mbox{Nm}$, so:

$$
P = (3.5)(0.0175) \mbox{Nm/s} \\
P = 61\mbox{mW} \\
$$

So, based on your problem description, nearly any motor you can find will work, with the exception of the very smallest hobby motors. For instance, [this motor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B1KZ8UU) has a rated speed of 120rpm, a rated torque of 0.6Nm, which is over 30x your requirement, for a rated mechanical power of about 7.5W.

A couple notes of caution, though:

These calculations make the assumptions that there is no friction *and* that there is no inertia between the motor and the shutter. Regarding bearings, I would probably use *bushings*, which are basically wear parts but are significantly less expensive and smaller than true bearings for light loads. I would definitely consider using at least one bushing to help minimize bending forces and wear on the output shaft bearing in the motor.

Without a better description (read: picture) of what your intended setup is I can't comment any further than this. In general, though, find the torque, speed, and power rating for the motor and add some performance margin and then just search the Internet. *You* have to finish the design before anyone here can comment specifically on it.

Comment: Thanks Chuck for the nice and accurate calculation. I hope my update clarifies the intended design.